# Advice on web app to make pdf (documents) library

Tags: cms, pdf, library

I want to create an online pdf library. Is there any free solution exist, CMS or something?

It should allow to upload pdfs, search documents and download them

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google Docs API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/) to handle this (upload, search and download). The server side code can be pretty minimal thereafter.